# How do I find the area of this domain given $ D = \{(x,y) | x^2 \le y, x+y \le 6, y - 2x \le 3?$

Tags: integration, area

I tried to find the area of a domain, but no luck. Possibly, there could be integrals involved, but that just makes my job harder. Can you help me?

The domain is:$ D = \{(x,y) | x^2 \le y, x+y \le 6, y - 2x \le 3\}.$

Comment: Did you try drawing it?

Comment: Have no idea how to draw it. Besides, i dont think there is a need to

Comment: having some kind of a visualization will surely help solving it

Comment: @B.S. You know of integrals but cannot sketch function inequalities? I am confused, what class is this for? And if your area is some curved shape- integrals would only make life easier, as it is literally, the only way to compute such an area.

Comment: well, the problem is, i dont know how to reach to the integral solution. I dont know what to integrate

Comment: Drawing it will help figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few quick clarifications before I answer your question. First off, your intuition is right, integrals do help us in finding areas under curves. For more information on that, I would suggest you use resources such as [this one.](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/integration-introduction.html)

However, as you may have already learnt, if the curves are in the form of straight lines and they make simple shapes that we already know the area of, well, we can calculate their area!

First off, we must sketch the given inequations on a graph to get some better intuition as to what we're dealing with here. For this here are some basic forms of equations you'll be encountering:

> 1. $y = mx + c$: this is the equation of a straight line with slope $m$
>    and y-intercept as $c$
> 2. $y = x^2$: this is an upward-opening parabola cutting through the origin.

Now, when we convert the given inequations to the standard forms we get:

$x + y \le 6$

$y \le -x + 6$

You will notice this is in the form $y = mx + c$ where $m = -1$ and $c = 6$. The only difference is that it uses a $\le$ sign instead of an $=$ sign. This simply tells us that everything 'below' the constructed line is what this equation is representing. We have now formed the first bound. Doing the same for the remaining:

$y - 2x \le 3$

$y \le 2x + 3$

Here, the slope is 2 and the y-intercept is 3. This tells us the area below that line is what we're looking at and we now have our second bound. Finally:

$y \ge x^2$

So we construct our parabola and this curve forms our third bound. So far, the figure looks something like this:

[image: Graph]

Where the area that is intersected by all 3 colours is the required area.

Now, to calculate this area is a tiny bit tricky considering you have a parabola added to the mix. Here you would have to use some basic integration knowledge to solve the question.

For this, I need to find three points - 1. The point of intersection between the two lines, 2. The point of intersection of the parabola with one of the lines and 3. The point of intersection of the parabola with the other line.

To do this, I will solve the equations simultaneously [2 at a time to get the respective POIs]

Taking parabola and line 1,

$y = 2x + 3$ and $y = x^2$

We only need to x coordinate of this as all we're looking for is the lower limit of our integral.

$2x + 3 = x^2$

$x^2 - 3x + x - 3 = 0$

$x = -1, 3$ and as we know that the POI is in the second quadrant so x = -1 is the lower limit.

For the upper limit, solving:

$y = x^2$ and $y = -x + 6$

$x = 2$

and finally solving for POI of the two lines, we get:

$y = -x + 6$ and $y = 2x + 3$

$x = 1$

Now, to integrate, we can split the figure into two parts like so along the line x = 1:

[image: Graph 2]

Now, from x = -1 to x = 1 the area of each infinitesimally small vertical strip is (y(line) - y(parabola)).dx

$= (2x + 3 - x^2)dx$

integrating this from x = -1 to 1:

$\int_{-1}^1 (-x^2 + 2x + 3) \,dx$

$= \frac{16}{3}$

Repeating a similar process for the remaining figure we have:

$\int_1^2 (-x^2 - x + 6) \,dx$

$= \frac{13}{6}$

So total area = $7.5$ sq. units

[Note: This is all pretty basic calculus. It seems lengthy because I was trying to explain it in as much detail as possible.]

Answer (score 2):

Noting that the intersection points are at $(1,5)$, $(2,4)$ and $(-1,1)$, the area is
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}(2x+3)dx+\int_{1}^{2}(6-x)dx-\int_{-1}^{2}x^{2}dx=\frac{15}{2}
$$